# R ggplot Plot from data in one data frame, label axis ticks using data frame a different data frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 data sets. In `data`, `b` is encoded as numeric values. `data1` represents the original in which `b` is chr data.

I would like to plot a box plot using the numeric data from `data` but pull the y-axis tick labels from the chr data `b` in `data1`. Is this possible?

Toy data:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
                   b = c(10,10,11,11,12,12,12,13,13,13,14,14,14,15,15),
                   c = c('x','y','y','x','y','y','x','y','y','x','y','y','x','x','y'))

data1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
                   b = c('never','never','rare','rare','some','some','some','most','most','most','often','often','often','always','always'),
                   c = c('x','y','y','x','y','y','x','y','y','x','y','y','x','x','y'))
```

My attempt to achieve the outcome using `scale_y_discrete`:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x = as.factor(a), y = b, fill = c))+
      geom_boxplot()+
  scale_y_discrete(data1$b,labels=unique(data1$b))
```

[image]

As you can see, the y-axis tick labels are not displaying as anticipated.

For further reference, this is to be used on a far larger data set as part of a Shiny application. The plot forms a reactive element and so I need to avoid hard-coding the actual label names.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As your `b` variable is continuous you have to use `scale_y_continuous`. While for your example data `scale_y_continuous(labels = unique(data1$b))` will work, personally I would suggest to use a named vector of labels which is less error prone and assigns labels to numeric values:

```r
library(ggplot2)

labels <- unique(data1$b)
names(labels) <- 10:15

ggplot(data,aes(x = as.factor(a), y = b, fill = c))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = labels)
```

[image]

Comment: `names(labels) = unique(data$b)` wouldn't be a good idea?!

Comment: Thanks for your response @stefan. I am suitably embarrassed over the `discrete` error...    Regarding your alternative solution, my concern comes in the assignment , `names(labels) <- 10:15`. Given the content will be dynamic, I cannot statically assign the range `10:15`. Would you mind elaborating on the potential errors of just using `scale_y_continuous(labels = unique(data1$b))`

Comment: The issue is that using `labels = unique(data1$b)` there is no link between the numeric values from data$b and the labels from data1$b. Hence whether the right labels are assigned depends on whether you labels are in the right order. That's what I mean by error prone. If you are sure that this will not be an issue than  `labels = unique(data1$b)` is fine.

Comment: @shafee Yeah, this will work for the specific example. But it depends on `data$b` and `data1$b` being in the same order. In general I think this is error prone and sooner or latter you will run nto issues. That's why I would suggest and always go for recoding the data or to use a lookup table to ensure that the numerics are assigned the correct labels.

Comment: @stefan Thank you for elaborating. I see the point. Given that statically defining a range as per your example wont work for my actual use case, I am guessing that using a look up table is going to be the best route. However, this is something I have no experience with at all and will have to research.

Comment: Do that. One question I would ask is what's the reason that you have a df with the b value recoded as numerics and essentially the same df where the b values are coded with there labels?  Perhaps there is a way to have only one dataset containing both the numerics and the labels, e.g. I work quite regularly with survey data which is passed to me as a csv with numeric data but also a file containing the variable and value labels (ie. a lookup table) which in a first step I "merge" together.